# In Thunderbirds, what is the badge on Parker’s cap?

Tags: thunderbirds

Does anybody know, or have a clear picture of what the badge is on Parker's cap is, in the Original Thunderbirds TV show?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The badge from the TV series doll can be seen here

[image: Parker Thunderbirds 1]
[image: Parker Thunderbirds 2]

I believe it's intended to be a stylised (and simplified) version of the traditional "[Chauffeur's Cockade](http://images.library.wisc.edu/HumanEcol/EFacs/MillineryBooks/MBWebbHeritage/reference/humanecol.mbwebbheritage.i0025.pdf)"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, Thankyou! :D